# RewriteRule but not if URL contains

Tags: .htaccess, parameters, url-rewriting

I need to modify this `RewriteRule` not to do something if a parameter is in the URL.

`RewriteRule ^img/potm/([^/]+) timthumb.php?src=img/potm/$1&h=112&w=160&zc=1`

I'm thinking, if there is a special parameter in the match, then it wont do it? I assume this has to be done with two rules right?

**Example**

A good URL will only contain the filename, `www.example.com/img/potm/blah.jpg` this will fall through to the `RewriteRule`. A bad URL will be `www.example.com/img/potm/blah.jpg?fail` which wont be parsed by the Rule.

Comment: So .. you only want the rewrite rule to engage if Query String is EMPTY, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make RewriteRule work ONLY if query string is **empty**, you have to add this line just before `RewriteRule` line:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
```

If rule in your question is the actual rewrite rule, then it will look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^img/potm/([^/]+) timthumb.php?src=img/potm/$1&h=112&w=160&zc=1
```

Comment: Perfect! I never knew about that line!